# how to pass an argument to GDB python scripts when they're loaded

Tags: python, gdb, environment-variables

I need to pass to a GDB python custom command an argument or environmental variable to change a path, but so that it would also have a default one;
I.e. when I do `source pythonfile.py` I could set a path according to the argument.

This is basically what I want to do

```
PATH = "/some/path/" if not os.environ.get("CUSTOM_PATH") else os.environ.get("CUSTOM_PATH")
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up passing it directly to GDB, i.e. `CUSTOM_PATH=/path/to/thing gdb ...`